read a RGB bit signal using the RMT module on an esp32-c3 devkit
I am trying to use the RMT module on the esp32-c3 devkit to read a RGB bit signal which drives a WS2812b. The bit signal is around 800 kHz therefore the basic PulseIn() command on Arduino IDE cannot accurately read a frequency this high. I am trying to implement a RX channel using the RMT module but I am receiving some errors. I have attached the code and Serial monitor output below. How can I rectify this? Are there any alternative solutions?
#include "driver/rmt.h"
#include "freertos/FreeRTOS.h"
#include "freertos/task.h"

RingbufHandle_t rb = NULL;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  rmt_channel_t channel = RMT_CHANNEL_0;
  gpio_num_t gpio = GPIO_NUM_5;

  rmt_config_t rx_config;
  rx_config.channel = channel;
  rx_config.rmt_mode = RMT_MODE_RX;
  rx_config.gpio_num = gpio;
  rx_config.mem_block_num = 1;
  rx_config.clk_div = 10;
  rx_config.rx_config.idle_threshold = 10000;
  rx_config.rx_config.filter_ticks_thresh = 0.2;
  rx_config.rx_config.filter_en = true;

  // Initializing rmt module////
  ESP_ERROR_CHECK(rmt_config(&rx_config));
  ESP_ERROR_CHECK(rmt_driver_install(channel, 1000, 0));

  rmt_get_ringbuf_handle(channel, &rb);

  rmt_rx_start(channel, true);
  Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  assert(rb != NULL);

  size_t length;

  rmt_item32_t *items =
      (rmt_item32_t *)xRingbufferReceive(rb, &length, pdMS_TO_TICKS(1000));
  if (items) {
    int num_items = length / sizeof(rmt_item32_t);
    printf("Received %d items\n", num_items);

    for (int i = 0; i < num_items; i++) {
      printf("Item %d: Level0: %d, Duration0: %d, Level1: %d, Duration1: %d\n",
             i, items[i].level0, items[i].duration0, items[i].level1,
             items[i].duration1);
    }

    // Return buffer back to ring buffer
    vRingbufferReturnItem(rb, (void *)items);
  }
}

The Serial output is below
> rst:0x3 (RTC_SW_SYS_RST),boot:0xc (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT)
Saved PC:0x40381ef2
SPIWP:0xee
mode:DIO, clock div:2
load:0x3fcd5810,len:0x438
load:0x403cc710,len:0x90c
load:0x403ce710,len:0x2624
entry 0x403cc710
E (97) rmt: rmt_set_gpio(534): RMT CHANNEL ERR
E (98) rmt: rmt_config(686): set gpio for RMT driver failed
ESP_ERROR_CHECK failed: esp_err_t 0x102 (ESP_ERR_INVALID_ARG) at 0x40385449
file: "C:\Arduino Codes\RMT_module_initial\RMT_module_initial.ino" line 25
func: void setup()
expression: rmt_config(&rx_config)


wait, the RMT module is for decoding infrared remote signals, right, or am I confusing it with things?

As far as I know it can receive PWM signals as well and is not confined to infrared signals though…

I didn't find indication of that in the ESP32-C3 Technical Manual's chapter "33 – Remote Control Peripheral (RMT)"; it doesn't mention PWM, or pulse length measurements. Could you point me to the source of your knowledge?

hm you could be right, one migth use the carrier high / low /idle thresholds with a state machine, as well.

It’s been a while since I’ve used the RMT, but from what I can recall with the original ESP32 you could setup the RMT fifo depth then use DMA to move the data into memory. Then you’d need to identify the reset pulse to resend the stream. On a dual core ESP32 there’s the possibility on dedicating on core to decoding the bitstream. @MarcusMüller the RMT measures the pulse high and low time as 16 bit timer counts and stores the 32 bit result into a fifo. I’ve used it to read IBM 3270 data. You could probably use it to read floppy disk data as well - probably someone has done this already…..

There is already a library example using RMT for controlling WS2812 RGB LED that comes with your ESP32 Arduino installation.

The WS2182 protocol is really just binary PWM. So you'd decode it as PWM.
On other 32 bit microcontrollers, you'd do something like using a timer unit to count the length of high/low interval, and trigger a PWM unit to transfer that value into convenient ring buffer, from which your software can occasionally read the durations, and thus decode the signal.
Now, doesn't seem like ESP32-C3 has any DMA attached to timer units. So, you could use a free-running timer (which increases monotonously), and just write an interrupt service routine to be triggered by an input pin changing state. In that interrupt, you'd get the current timer value, and subtract the last from it, to know how long the last high or low lasted.
You must implement the protocol state machine: you would have

a FIRSTHALFBIT state, in which you save the current timer value to a static variable last_rising_edge and exit the interrupt handler.
a SECONDHALFBIT state which you enter when you see a falling edge, at which point you get the current timer value, subtract last_rising_edge from that to get a different static variable delta_t, and exit the interrupt handler.
a BIT_DONE state, which you enter when you see a rising edge. At that point, you get the current timer value, subtract the last_rising_edge. If that difference is larger than Treset (from the WS2812 datasheet), you immediately enter the RESET state. 
If that difference is > 2 * delta_t, have a 0, else you have 1. You shift that bit into an 8bit static variable current_byte, and if this is the 8. shift, you put current_byte at the current write position in a byte ring buffer, and increase the write pointer of that. You enter the FIRSTHALFBIT state immediately.
a RESET state, which you enter when there's a period of low longer thant Treset (WS2812 datasheet!), at which point you'll copy the first 8 bytes from a ringbuffer (call it buffer) to three 8 bit variables (green, red and blue, in that order), do whatever processing you want on these color values, shift the read pointer of that ring buffer by 3 bytes, and repeat until your read pointer would overtake the write pointer,


My concern with the state machine implementation is that since the pulse time for WS2812B leds are between 0.4-0.8 microseconds, will the esp32-c3 be able to read nano-second pulses? according to my understanding i dont think a basic interrupt routine can read pulses to such a high resolution

that thing runs at 80 MHz or more, right? so, how many clock cycles do you have per pulse?

I think the total length of the pulse is 1us. However, we need to be able to measure the rising edge and falling edge with a time difference of 400-800ns(to distinguish between ones and zeros). To my knowledge the lowest possible count on an esp32 is to microseconds. Dont we need a resolution of at least multiples of nanoseconds(for example resolution of 10 or 100ns) to measure the time difference.

you should be able to read the current state of any GPIO CSR at CPU clock speeds. I don't really see a problem there; I'd argue it's one of the things the C3 was optimized for. (the edges are going to be APB bus clock synchronous, but even that is much faster than you need). See ESP32-C3 TRM (version 1.1) page 157;
